# Which one is correct: "in the fierce fighting of the war" or "in the fierce fighting in the war"?

Tags: prepositions

Could you tell me which preposition I use in the follwing sentences: *of* or *in*?

> One of my grandparents fell in the fierce fighting **of**/**in** World War Two.

What I am trying to say is that my grandfather fell during some fighting in/of the war not specific battle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use "of" because you are not referencing a specific battle but you are describing the fighting of that war. I would say:

> One of my grandparents fell in the fierce fighting of World War Two.

If you were referencing a specific battle, you might want to infer that the fighting in this battle was more fierce than in other battles of the same war, but you are not doing that.

You are telling us that the fighting in World War Two was fierce. However, you are not making an entire sentence of it; you are just fitting "fierce fighting" into the sentence as a description. For this reason, I think "of" works best; I think it is what most authors of the English language would use in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

There is no mistake in saying either, except a difference in meaning:

> One of my grandparents got into fierce fighting *in* World War
> Two. ( *"**during** = at some point of time during WWII"* );

,while using "of" as a preposition would indicate the following meaning:

> One of my grandparents got into *the* fierce fighting *of* World War
> Two. (*" the genitive case here would imply uniqueness of the fighting
> that is certainly written to **history** mostly because the event has changed the course of it, or takes an important part in it "*);

for instance:

> "The battle for Moscow was the biggest battle *of* World War II -- the
> biggest battle of all time."

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But, I  am confused. What I want to say is that my grandparent fell in some, not specified, event of World War Two, which is why I use the word "fighting" not "battle." You say that using "of" makes it specific, but doesn't the use of "the" makes something specific.

Comment: You said "my grandfather got into the fierce fighting in World War Two". Does't the use of "the" makes in as specific as your second example?

Comment: *The genitive case* implies the meaning more uniquely. There is nothing wrong with using "the" article.

Comment: Could you tell me how the meaning would change if I said "One of my grandparents got into fierce fighting in World War Two." I dropped the artickle.

Comment: Despite the fact that is not the question included in the OP, I will let you know. Without "the" the meaning would be "the whole idea or substance of fighting", while with "the" specifies the meaning earlier pointed out in the context, or the author wants to imply his specific interpretation. You should google "a conversation vs conversation", or try referring to your favorite grammar for more information on *Articles and Determiners.*

Comment: Thank you! You are of great help That's exactly what I wanted to know

Comment: But, that raises one more question? Is there any difference in meaning between "My grandfther fell in fierce fighting IN World War Two" and "My grandfather fell in fierce fighting OF World War Two"?

Comment: Let's wait for other users to see my answer. Just to make sure we are not going overboard.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110747/discussion-between-alex-raw-and-dmytro-ohope).